# iptables starts dropping packets; temporarily fixed by doing restart; only from home

Tags: iptables

I am running a small apache2/iRedMail server but I am having an issue with iptables. After a while of working correctly (hours) my server is unreachable **edit: from my home internet connection** on some ports (ports 80, 443 tested, edit: apache?) until I restart the iptables service (`sudo service iptables restart`). Doing this makes everything work again! I do not know what could cause this issue, especially because it occurs hours after restarting the iptables service.

Which logfiles can I look into? The `kern.log` file shows nothing obvious (I read that it contains information about iptables).

All iptables rules are configured in the standard file used in iRedMail which is `/etc/default/iptables`.

Thanks in advance!

edit1: output of `iptables -L -n -v`

```
user@server:~$ sudo iptables -L -n -v                                                                                             
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 102 packets, 19966 bytes)                                                                                  
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     
 9500 2164K fail2ban-dovecot  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,25,587,110,9
95,143,993,4190                                                                                                                     
18543 6112K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED                  
  229 13256 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                       
   33  1628 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80                                 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8888                               
  109  6520 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443                                
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25                                 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587                                
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110                                
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:995                                
   14   808 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143                                
   18  1104 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993                                
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:17655                              
    1    60 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8                                 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)                                                                                      
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 16026 packets, 9143K bytes)                                                                             
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     

Chain fail2ban-dovecot (1 references)                                                                                               
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     
 9500 2164K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

edit2: it seems that my iptables file was altered on december 15th:
This is what it is now:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Mon Dec 15 23:35:36 2014                                                                    
*filter                                                                                                                             
:INPUT DROP [0:0]                                                                                                                   
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]                                                                                                                 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [137:211520]                                                                                                         
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT                                                                             
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT                                                                                                            
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT                                                                                         
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT                                                                                       
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT                                                                                        
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT                                                                                         
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT                                                                                        
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT                                                                                        
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT                                                                                        
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT                                                                                        
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT                                                                                        
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 17655 -j ACCEPT                                                                                      
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT                                                                                    
COMMIT                                                                                                                              
# Completed on Mon Dec 15 23:35:36 2014
```

This is what it was before, extracted this from an older backup:
There are differences besides the comments.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                              
# This file is part of iRedMail, which is an open source mail server                                                                
# solution for Red Hat(R) Enterprise Linux, CentOS, Debian and Ubuntu.                                                              
#                                                                                                                                   
# iRedMail is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify                                                                  
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by                                                              
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or                                                                 
# (at your option) any later version.                                                                                               
#                                                                                                                                   
# iRedMail is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,                                                                       
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of                                                                    
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the                                                                     
# GNU General Public License for more details.                                                                                      
#                                                                                                                                   
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License                                                                 
# along with iRedMail.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.                                                                 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                              

#                                                                                                                                   
# Sample iptables rules. It should be localted at:                                                                                  
#   /etc/sysconfig/iptables                                                                                                         
#                                                                                                                                   
# Shipped within iRedMail project:                                                                                                  
#   * http://iRedMail.googlecode.com/                                                                                               
#                                                                                                                                   

*filter                                                                                                                             
:INPUT DROP [0:0]                                                                                                                   
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]                                                                                                                 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]                                                                                                                

# Keep state.                                                                                                                       
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT                                                                             

# Loop device.                                                                                                                      


-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT                                                                                                            

# http, https                                                                                                                       
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT                                                                                                
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT                                                                                              
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT                                                                                               

# smtp, submission                                                                                                                  
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT                                                                                                
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT                                                                                               


# pop3, pop3s                                                                                                                       
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT                                                                                               
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT                                                                                               

# imap, imaps                                                                                                                       
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT                                                                                               
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT                                                                                               

# ssh                                                                                                                               
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 17655 -j ACCEPT                                                                                             
#-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT                                                                                             

# Allow PING from remote hosts.                                                                                                     
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT                                                                                 

# ejabberd                                                                                                                          
#-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5222 -j ACCEPT                                                                                             
#-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5223 -j ACCEPT                                                                                             
#-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5280 -j ACCEPT                                                                                             

# ldap/ldaps                                                                                                                        
#-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 389 -j ACCEPT                                                                                              
#-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 636 -j ACCEPT                                                                                              

# ftp.                                                                                                                              
#-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT                                                                                               
#-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT                                                                                               

COMMIT
```

new output of `iptables -L -n -v`

```
user@server:~$ sudo iptables -L -n -v                                                                                                      
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1879 packets, 840K bytes)                                                                                
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     
  694  227K fail2ban-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,25,587,110,9
95,143,993,4190                                                                                                                     
  694  227K fail2ban-dovecot  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,25,587,110,9
95,143,993,4190                                                                                                                     
  694  227K fail2ban-roundcube  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,25,587,110
,995,143,993,4190                                                                                                                   
    0     0 fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22                              

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)                                                                                    
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1706 packets, 707K bytes)                                                                               
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     

Chain fail2ban-dovecot (1 references)                                                                                               
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     
  694  227K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                       

Chain fail2ban-postfix (1 references)                                                                                               
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     
  694  227K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                       

Chain fail2ban-roundcube (1 references)                                                                                             
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     
  694  227K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                       

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)                                                                                                   
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                     
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

edit3: output of `sudo cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack`, server ip replaced. Seems to be quite short.

```
ipv4     2 udp      17 145 src=<SERVERIP> dst=213.239.239.166 sport=123 dport=123 src=213.239.239.166 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=123 dport=123 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2     
ipv4     2 tcp      6 429127 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=39571 dport=3306 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=3306 dport=39571 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 tcp      6 100 TIME_WAIT src=92.121.32.40 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=4707 dport=443 src=<SERVERIP> dst=92.121.32.40 sport=443 dport=4707 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431999 ESTABLISHED src=92.121.32.40 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=4709 dport=443 src=<SERVERIP> dst=92.121.32.40 sport=443 dport=4709 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 
use=2                                                                                                                                                                          
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431291 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=46386 dport=389 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=389 dport=46386 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2     
ipv4     2 tcp      6 429127 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=39572 dport=3306 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=3306 dport=39572 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431999 ESTABLISHED src=92.121.32.40 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=4705 dport=443 src=<SERVERIP> dst=92.121.32.40 sport=443 dport=4705 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 
use=2                                                                                                                                                                          
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431975 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=50519 dport=4200 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=4200 dport=50519 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 udp      17 112 src=<SERVERIP> dst=213.239.239.164 sport=123 dport=123 src=213.239.239.164 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=123 dport=123 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2     
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431999 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=50515 dport=4200 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=4200 dport=50515 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 tcp      6 100 TIME_WAIT src=92.121.32.40 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=4704 dport=443 src=<SERVERIP> dst=92.121.32.40 sport=443 dport=4704 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431999 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=50517 dport=4200 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=4200 dport=50517 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 tcp      6 429127 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=39573 dport=3306 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=3306 dport=39573 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431975 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=50523 dport=4200 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=4200 dport=50523 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431975 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=50521 dport=4200 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=4200 dport=50521 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 tcp      6 100 TIME_WAIT src=92.121.32.40 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=4701 dport=443 src=<SERVERIP> dst=92.121.32.40 sport=443 dport=4701 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431975 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=50525 dport=4200 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=4200 dport=50525 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2   
ipv4     2 udp      17 113 src=<SERVERIP> dst=213.239.239.165 sport=123 dport=123 src=213.239.239.165 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=123 dport=123 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2     
ipv4     2 tcp      6 100 TIME_WAIT src=92.121.32.40 dst=<SERVERIP> sport=4706 dport=443 src=<SERVERIP> dst=92.121.32.40 sport=443 dport=4706 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 429127 ESTABLISHED src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=39570 dport=3306 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=3306 dport=39570 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
```

Comment: Could it be fail2ban that's cauing it? Keep a line open to your server (in tmux, which has a clock that prevents inactive connection killing by routers) and once it doesn't accept new connections anymore, look at iptables again.

Comment: Check out the fail2ban log file (/var/log/fail2ban.log), it indicates which IP and which jail creates the banning. If it is a jail from Fail2ban, you found. If it is not then...

Comment: How consistent is the problem?  i.e. can you reproduce the problem reliably?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem but it now happened to me again. I noticed that I do have SSH access over port 17655, so that is NOT broken as I thought. The fail2ban log has no recent entries. The newest is from three days ago. Right now there are 48 entries in the conntrack log.

Comment: Very strange! I noticed that this only happens from home! I cannot access my server from here but it works from my phone and from work. What is that?

Comment: @elagil So, from home, you can't access the SSH port. Can you access the other ports when you can't do SSH? And, after 'restarting' iptables, you can access SSH again?

Comment: PS: Please post the result of `iptables-save` *when* you can't access the services on your server.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are hitting the limit of the conntrack table.

iptables keeps track of each TCP connection that you "accept" in a table called "conntrack". This table is used so that future packets (both send and received) are permitted automatically. i.e. it keeps the "state" of each connection. Because it tracks which ephemeral port was used, this is more secure than stateless firewalling.  http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html

This connections are stored in memory (the "conntrack" table, or state table).  The size of the table is limited.  Once the table is full, no new connections are accepted even if you have a "APPROVE" rule that matches it.

You can view the table by reading the file `/proc/net/nf_conntrack`:

    `cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack`

You can count the number of lines in the table to see how full it is:

    `wc -l /proc/net/nf_conntrack`

You can see what the max table size is by reading the sysctl variable:

    `# sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max
    net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 4194304`

You can set the size using sysctl.  Be sure to update `/etc/sysctl.conf` so that the setting is also made on reboot.

My guess is that you have it set to the default, which is very small.

My recommendations:

- Increase the size of the table.
- Your monitoring system should track how many connections are in the table so you can see how it increases over time.
- Set your monitoring system to alert if it is getting near full so you can increase it before there are problems.

Comment: Actually the limit is 65536 with only 34 lines filled in nf_conntrack. Although the explanation sounds reasonable I guess that I do not have this problem. Is this file cleared on reboot or anything? As a side not I have not had blocked connections since yesterday when I modified the iptables file.

Comment: Added the output of `cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack` above